# Catching an Exception thrown by an embed URL in Flex

Tags: apache-flex, iframe

I am new in Flex, and I am trying to retrieve info from an external url's information. So right now I am using a call a url from another server when the user clicks on the link( this brings up the IFrame with the url embeded). If successful (based on arguments sent with the url) then a correct page will load up. But, if unsuccessful, ( i will get a exception error on the webpage embeded on the link i have given) then i need to display a pop up that says error and return back to the previous page. Is there a way to check if i am getting an exception error from the url site i am retrieving?

Is this possible to load the urls info first and if success then load, and if not bring pop up?

** additional note, I am trying to catch a servlet exception http 500.

Thank you in advance for any help.

Below is a peice of the code, so when this component is called, by a click button, it puts this IFrame in the view contents with the url, but i want to know if the http status code is recieving 500, or 400 etc. so i can stop this call and load up instead a error popup.

** Added code snippets

```
   <mxmlcomp:IFrame id="iFrameViewBoxA" 
                 source="{my.url}"
                 width="100%" height="100%"
                 frameLoad="iFrameContents()"
                 />
   <script>... 
   private function iFrameContents():void {
            ExternalInterface.call("iFrameContents()");
        }
   </script>
```

Comment: Could you add some code snippets?  For Adobe AIR you can check the HTTP response code of the call, but I'm not sure if this is possible in Flex.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do this in an iframe due to security restrictions. This is actually a limit in the browser, and not anything to do with Flex.

Comment: But isnt it possible to send a request and recieve the status back from http? Such as noting if the site is giving an http response code back 500, 400 and etc? also not that i am getting a servlet error back from the site http 500. just more info if any case

Comment: No, if this mxml is actually rendering out to a true iframe that's not under your same domain, you cannot do anything with the iframe's content or request. An alternative could be using the URLLoader to retrieve the content of the external page and then working with it directly, if there's no actual interaction by the user required. What are you trying to do with this data you get back?